# Alter check constraint as 'C' to 'C%'

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I want to alter check constraint as 'C' to 'C%' . My table is already created.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT_MASTER (CLIENTNO varchar2(6)check (CLIENTNO LIKE 'C'),
                            NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,ADDRESS1 VARCHAR2(30),ADDRESS2        VARCHAR2(30),CITY VARCHAR2(15), PINCODE NUMBER(8),STATE VARCHAR2(15),BALDUENUMBER(10,2),primary key (CLIENTNO));
```

Comment: here i want to alter check constraint as 'C' to 'C%' . my table is already created

Comment: in which database u r working??? My sql or sql server ???

Comment: Judging by `VARCHAR2` it have to be Oracle

Answer (score 1):

You have to drop and recreate the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENT_MASTER
   DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>;
ALTER TABLE CLIENT_MASTER
  ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> CHECK (CLIENTNO LIKE 'C%');
```

To find the current name of the constraint, since you didn't specify it explicitly in `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_constraints
 WHERE table_name = 'CLIENT_MASTER'
   AND constraint_type = 'C'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86127/1)** demo

Comment: @user2981555 Did it help after all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [SSMS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191273.aspx), but if you want to use SQL, you have to [delete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187626.aspx) it then [recreate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190377.aspx) it.